# Increasing the x and y values of a point by a value

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3

I have a point dataset with many overlapping points. For the locations where I have overlap, I want to increase the x and/or y location for 1 of the points by 0.1 meters. I need to do this consecutively until there are no points that overlap but are "neighborly". I cannot google this question well enough to get an answer. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with a bit of brain power. If this can be improved upon, please do:

```
CREATE TABLE p797.points2 AS 
SELECT * 
FROM p797.points 
WHERE gid NOT IN (
        SELECT gid
        FROM (
            SELECT gid, count(gid) count
            FROM p797.points 
            GROUP BY gid
              ) a
        WHERE count > 1
        );

INSERT INTO p797.points2 (gid, geom)
SELECT gid, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x + ((rownumber - 1)/10), y +((rownumber - 1)/10)),3400)
FROM
    (
    SELECT  gid, ST_X(geom) x, ST_Y(geom) y, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY gid) rownumber
    FROM p797.points 
    WHERE gid IN (
            SELECT gid
            FROM (
                SELECT gid, count(gid) count, status 
                FROM p797.points 
                GROUP BY gid, status
                  ) a
            WHERE count > 1
             )
    ) c
```